# Check CSV for name, then update number or add the name

Tags: csv, batch-file

I want to write a batch file to keep track of how often people use a certain twitch points redeem in a CSV file.
The name of the user gets automatically provided to the batch file as an argument.
I then want the batch file to output the CSV file as a text file, preferably with formatting

I have little to no experience with batch files, so I need help writing it.

`CSV 'C:\namelist' (name, redeems)`

- test, 1
- testname, 2
- anothertest, 1

So the batch needs to look through this file for the argument name.
If it can find it, increment the redeems.
If not, add the name, and set its redeems to 1.

After I want the CSV to be output to a text file as such:

`TXT 'C:\namelistoutput'`

test(1), testname(2), anothertest(1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't help you to write your scripts, we only help you to fix a specific issue with your own submitted script. We have thousands of questions and answers on this site for you to use as a basis for writing your own code. There is an excellent search facility at the top of each site page, which has been specifically placed there for convenience.

Comment: Maybe you don't, I've literally seen people post the exact same format as me and get actually usable answers.

Comment: I'm telling you the purpose of this site. Did you take the site [tour], and read through the content linked within [ask], before posting your question? _You could, of course, just be argumentative and hope that another commentor likes helping lazy account holders with of topic requests, (with insufficient information), instead._

Comment: Oh I am argumentative, you're joking right? I am simply asking for help because after 2 hours of searching I found nothing that helps me and seen people ask in the exact same way that I am now. If you don't want to help, don't. You don't have to attack me for literally doing what others are doing too (with success and without getting attacked)

Comment: `for /?` for how to read the file line by line, `if /?` to compare it, `echo /?` to write, 
 [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to redirect it to a new file.

Comment: If your question had included any indication of your searches, code you thought may help, and something you'd tested unsuccessfully, then perhaps I'd have posted something which you interpreted as less of an attack. We aren't mind readers, and we are not a free code writing service. If site guidelines have been ignored or relaxed by others previously, it doesn't make those obsolete or reduce their relevance today.